# What is an adjective to describe someone who constructs their moral views based on convenience?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Until recently I believed that "self-righteous" describes someone whose ideas of right and wrong are conveniently aligned with their own situation, in a way that does not require them to put much effort into doing what is right or avoiding what is wrong and allows them to judge others while being immune or resistant to the same judgement themselves.

Apparently this is not what self-righteous means. So what word could be used to describe this? Compound words are fine, obviously.

Examples:

- Someone who was born rich saying that people living in poverty are simply lacking ambition.
- Someone who cannot afford a plane ticket or car bragging about saving the environment by not using fossil fuel.
- Being quick to judge other people's misbehavior but blaming your own misbehavior on something beyond your control.

Example sentence:

> Being mad at Laura for keeping a minor secret from you when you've cheated on her is very ______ of you.

Comment: Your three examples all point in different directions. Someone in the first case who is blind to the poverty of others is not the same as someone in the second case who tries to point to a different reason than penury for not partaking of a luxury, and still different from the hypocritical nuances exhibited by the third person.

Comment: That is true, but all examples apply to the opening paragraph / question title.

Comment: Your title is very different from what you describe in your question. Your title describes "situational ethics." And a person who does such is a "rationalizing" person.

Comment: Consider opportunistic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does 'self-justifying' sound to you?

> **Self-justifying (adj):** Aiming to justify or excuse oneself or one's actions.
>
> Examples:
>
> - The politicians' stories are self-justifying.
> - The morally self-justifying claim of ‘hard work'.

[[Lexico]](https://www.lexico.com/definition/self-justifying)

Comment: Correct (though it doesn't fit the example sentence ... it seems that it's the example sentence that doesn't fit); I was just getting a reference. But you'll be able to make comments when you get a few rep points, so do add a linked and attributed reference. Wikipedia seems most appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for the info. How would I add a link in this case, maybe just do a definition search for "justifying"?

Comment: There have been other threads with answers like 'plaster saint', 'hypocrite', self-justifying', 'bigot' (hence the closure), but cut-and-past a relevant definition then include [name you want, like Wikidpedia](link address).

Comment: 'Self-justifying' is definitely a helpful suggestion. It describes the defensive part of the moral justification I'm referring to, but less so the more offensive/judgmental part: the example about rich people looking down on poor people.

Comment: ...So 'bigot' is more appropriate?

Comment: I was just pondering the "arrogance" inherent to the "self-righteous".

Comment: @Nathan: I did it for you. Press the 'edit' button to see how to format.

Comment: I've marked this answer as accepted, though it seems there isn't a word for my specific request. The first linked duplicate question is phrased broader and has a lot of potential answers, but I found none satisfying.

The most helpful inputs were 'self-justifying', 'bigot' and perhaps 'complacent'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "not self aware" which doesn't sound good, and I would think hypocritical would be the next best synonym.